# Has no method "nivoSlider" in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nivo-slider

I want to use nivoSlider in my Rails app, but I have a problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'

f.Callbacks.o                      jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith             jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready                     jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B               jquery.min.js:2
```

I use jquery 1.7.2 and nivoSlider 2.7.1.

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#slider").nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

All other code before **$(document).ready(function() {});** and with use jQuery work, but after **$("#slider").nivoSlider();** - not.

Answer (score 0):

`);` at the end

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#slider").nivoSlider();
});
```

And you don't need to include jQuery, it is included by default.

Comment: Also check the source of nivo slider. This is usually in assets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the correct path to the js file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think - yes. But how this cheaсk?